# Session warning in django and store user logout time due to session expire using object_log model

Tags: django, session

I am using middleware to handle session.and i want when session is going to expire before that user should get notification that session is going to expire do You want to continue.
if No then session will expire and transfer to login page otherwise continue.
when session expire due to inactive user then it must put data in log_object model.
code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import auth
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from object_log.models import LogItem
class AutoLogout:

    def process_request(self, request):

        if not request.user.is_authenticated() :
            return
        try:
            if (int(datetime.now().strftime('%s')) - int(request.session['last_touch']) - settings.LOG_OUT_CONFIRMATION * 60) > settings.AUTO_LOGOUT_DELAY * 60:
                pass

            if int(datetime.now().strftime('%s')) - int(request.session['last_touch']) > settings.AUTO_LOGOUT_DELAY * 60:
                data={'msg': 'Logged Out Successfully.'}
                #LogItem.objects.log_action('LOGOUT', request.user, request.user, data=data)
                auth.logout(request)
                del request.session['last_touch']
                return
        except KeyError:
            pass
        request.session['last_touch'] = datetime.now().strftime('%s')
```

I am using template to show notification.
please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: What problem? You haven't said what's going wrong.

Comment: Not able to give alert when time close to session expire and it through error when i uncomment LogItem.objects.log_action('LOGOUT', request.user, request.user, data=data).

Comment: Please, add error traceback and code of log_action method. Are you really need provide user twice?

Comment: if i remove one user from log_action it through error that it required 4 argument.